# Remote exec provisioner error: ssh handshake failed in terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I tried to run a basic print command in an ec2 intance created through terraform and provisioners (remote-exec with connection) but I am getting this ssh handshake failed error:

```
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec):   Host: 54.224.111.131
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec):   User: ubuntu
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec):   Password: false
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec):   Private key: true
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec):   Certificate: false
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: true
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec):   Target Platform: unix
aws_instance.ebony: Still creating... [7m20s elapsed]
aws_instance.ebony: Still creating... [7m30s elapsed]
aws_instance.ebony: Still creating... [7m40s elapsed]
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec):   Host: 54.224.111.131
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec):   User: ubuntu
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec):   Password: false
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec):   Private key: true
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec):   Certificate: false
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: true
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
aws_instance.ebony (remote-exec):   Target Platform: unix
╷
│ Error: remote-exec provisioner error
│ 
│   with aws_instance.ebony,
│   on main.tf line 20, in resource "aws_instance" "ebony":
│   20:     provisioner "remote-exec" {
│ 
│ timeout - last error: SSH authentication failed (ubuntu@54.224.111.131:22): ssh: handshake
│ failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods
│ remain
```

and here is my code for it:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "ebony" {
    ami                                  = "ami-07d9b9ddc6cd8dd30"
    instance_type                        = "t2.micro"
    key_name                             = "pls"
    subnet_id                            = "subnet-0c0d9c47d1c325ae1"
    security_groups                      = ["sg-088795c880e5d2a54"]

    tags = {
        Name = "orban"
    }

    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
            "echo 'hi from ubuntu vm'",
        ]

        connection {
            type        = "ssh"
            user        = "ubuntu"  
            private_key = file("/Users/orban/Desktop/pls.pem") 
            host        = self.public_ip
            timeout     = "5m"
        }
    }
}
```

checkboxes:

1. I have created a key value pair in aws and downloaded (pls.pem) and also added chmod 400 permissions in the appropriate directory
2. all the vpc, security lists, subnets and ami and also region are configured
3. after this error I tried ssh into ec2 instance and it worked and i was able to access the vm and both these commands worked:

   ssh -i ~/Desktop/pls.pem ubuntu@54.224.111.131

   ssh -i ~/Desktop/pls.pem ubuntu@ec2-54-224-111-131:22.compute-
   1.amazonaws.com

If there is anything to be changed or modified to this code and configuration please help.

Thank you